# Assertion failed: (Transform_is_valid(m))

Tags: ios, ios8

When I use `[myPath fill]` I get this

`Assertion failed: (transform_is_valid(m)), function CGMutablePathRef CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(CGPathRef, const CGAffineTransform *), file Paths/CGPATH/cc, line 168.`

I am implementing the same class in a new program. The original works. Although the original now has an "issue" wanting to "Validate Project Settings, Update to recommended settings". I've updated to ios8 between the two projects. I'm tempted to update to see if the original use will stop working too. Has a syntax changed or is ios8 needing another fix? I realize I'm not posting a lot of code but I can't narrow down any difference between the two.

Comment: argh, singleton screw up. Wasn't getting instruction to `fill`.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error..but I have no clue where to look.------

        `Assertion failed: (transform_is_valid(m)), function void            CGPathAddPath(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGPathRef), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 457.`
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In my case, it just wasn't getting the string. I think I just added an `NSLog` to display the contents of `myPath` and found it wasn't getting anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had a the same assert error at `[path stroke]`. It turned out my path only had a single `moveToPoint:` (with no subsequent `addLineToPoint:`). The assert message is just confusing...

So make sure you validate the instructions in the path.